# Flex Builder - How to set relative url in launch configuration properties?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I am trying to use a custom html wrapper for my application, but when I browse to choose my file it defaults to an absolute path to my custom-wrapper.html file.

I want to be able to pass off this project via SVN without any necessary configuration changes, but I'm not sure how to input a relative URL into this configuration dialog.  I tried standard back referencing from where my main actionscript application file is in the src directory (i.e. ../../bin-debug/custom-wrapper.html), but that does not work.

I think that I need to use properties like ${DOCUMENT} or ${FLEX_HOME}, but I'm not sure where these properties get defined and which ones come by default in the environment.  If anyone could point me towards a good reference, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand, but if your custom wrapper is meant to replace the standard html wrapper, why not replace the contents of [ProjectName]/html-template/index.template.html with the contents of your custom wrapper html file?

Comment: The file needs to have a custom name and path outside of the html-template folder, unfortunately.

Comment: I've run into this myself, haven't found a solution yet, sorry.